# How to create multidimensional dictionary in aspx from DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataTable users_table = db.GetRows("SELECT * FROM users");

int rowCount = users_table.Rows.Count;
int columnCount = users_table.Columns.Count;

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> baskets = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    baskets.Add(i, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        var colName = (users_table.Columns[i].ColumnName).ToString();
        var colValue = users_table.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        baskets[i].Add(colName, colValue);
        Response.Write(baskets[i]["user_id"].ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the error i got.

**ArrgumentException was unhandled by user code** at baskets[i].Add(colName, colValue);

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

What I'm doing wrong? I debug it and value of "i", "colName" and "colValue" is correct. Don't know why it's giving me error.
I'm newbie in .net programming

Comment: `Dictionary<Key,Value>` in .NET does not allow for idempotent `Add` and `Set` operations (unlike C++'s `map`, or associative-arrays in PHP and Python) so you must handle the two cases differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop `i` does not change and therefore the value of `colName` does not change. As a result you're adding the same key each time through:

```
var colName = (users_table.Columns[i].ColumnName).ToString();
baskets[i].Add(colName, colValue);
```

Most likely you meant to grab the name from `Columns[j]` instead of `Columns[i]` and this is a "second pair of eyes" problem.

FWIW, you can avoid this by using more descriptive counter variable names instead of the "traditional" `i` and `j`. Your code from the question translates to, which IMHO is easier to notice as "something's wrong with `Columns[row]`":

```
for (int row = 0; i < rowCount; row++)
{
    baskets.Add(row, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
    {
        var colName = (users_table.Columns[row].ColumnName).ToString();
        var colValue = users_table.Rows[row][col].ToString();
        baskets[row].Add(colName, colValue);
        Response.Write(baskets[row]["user_id"].ToString());
    }
}
```

---

Side note 1: [`DataTable.ColumnName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname(v=vs.110).aspx) is already a string, so your call to `ToString()` above is unnecessary.

Side note 2: Unless the "user_id" column is column 0, the `Response.Write` line is going to fail. Was this perhaps intended to be outside of the inner loop, or maybe just added for debugging purposes?

Side note 3: You can also keep a reference to the inner dictionary instead of using the indexer `baskets[row]` each time through the inner loop. Yes, this probably is a difference of microseconds, but:

```
for (int row = 0; i < rowCount; row++)
{
    var colDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    baskets.Add(row, colDic);
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
    {
        var colName = users_table.Columns[row].ColumnName;
        var colValue = users_table.Rows[row][col].ToString();
        colDic.Add(colName, colValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
baskets.Add(i, new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Because this adds an integer to the Dictionary that is `0` in the first iteration and then when it reaches to `baskets[i].Add(colName, colValue);` the dictionary has already added `0` in the key and would not be able to add the same item again. So removing that line will do make your code something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        var colName = users_table.Columns[j].ColumnName;
        var colValue = users_table.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        baskets[i].Add(colName, colValue);
        Response.Write(baskets[i]["user_id"].ToString());
    }
}
```

might do the trick for you

Comment: KeyNotFoundException